# Django Social Auth logout Users Automatically?

Tags: python-3.6, django-authentication, django-socialauth, django-1.11

I am using `django-social-auth` for authentication, which works fine, now i want to logout user on every 4 hours, how can i achieve this?

Since access_token is valid for 1hour, should we need to write any custom logic(middleware) for automatic logout without request from user or user will logout automatically after access_token expires?